# Fastest way for temporary data to read, write, update, delete

Tags: node.js, crud, system-design

I am trying to develop a messaging nodejs app and for the feature who_is_writing in the conversation, I want to quickly read, write, update, delete the data of who is writing.

I have MySql as the database, and if I try to store there I am afraid I may not be able to CRUD quickly. Because I want the client to have good UX.

I am still designing the database, so I haven't tried anything yet. Your comments or solutions are welcome.

ThankYou!

Comment: It's a messaging app, so presumably it can send messages directly between participants. Do you have something like socket.io? Can you do a whole-room broadcast? No need to involve the database for volatile state. By the way, you should look at XMPP (Jabber) - it's an open messaging standard with many extensions that solves many of the problems you're going to encounter; at one point, Facebook Messenger even used XMPP as its protocol. See how others have done it before you.

Comment: Thanks. I just learned the socket.io and implemented it, basically for who_is_wrting I do not even need to save it on any database.